# Windows command line using directory and EXE file parameters

Tags: windows, command-line

I have been trying to run an application I built and output it to a file. However, I am running into problems with the command line arguments required to do this.

This is an example of my problem using `ipconfig`.

The following command works:

```
ipconfig > output.txt
```

Whereas this will create the file, but not populate it with the `ipconfig` output:

```
start /D "C:\>WINDOWS\system32" ipconfig.exe > output.txt
```

I think it is the use of `start` that is causing this issue, but I'm not sure.

**SOLUTION**

This is the code which managed to solve the problem for me:

```
            char path[500]; // Create character array
            strcpy (path, "cd "); // Copy 'cd' into the array
            strcat (path, toolLocation); // Copy the path of the tool into the array
            strcat (path, " & ip.exe > output.txt"); // Append on the name of the exe and output to a file
            system (path); // Run the built array
```

I am creating a character array and then appending to it. The vital bit here was the `&` being used in the system call. This is working as an `and` and first cd'ing to the directory before executing the .exe file.

Comment: The `>` is redirecting the output of start. Why are you using start at all here?

Comment: Ah yes, that explains it. I am using start because I wish to start a console application from a GUI application. This console application is in program files so I was passing the string `"start /D "C:\Program Files\Tools\2012" ip.exe > output.txt"`. How could I go about achieving this ?

Answer (score 1):

In your command, the `>` is redirecting the output of `start` rather than the output of `ipconfig`. That explains why you are seeing nothing – `start` is simply not outputting anything.

Based on the comments to the question, you can achieve your goals with `ShellExecute` like this:

```
ShellExecute(
    0, 
    "open", 
    "cmd.exe", 
    "/C ipconfig > output.txt", 
    NULL, 
    SW_HIDE
);
```

Comment: This seems like the correct approach but It is failing to do anything. Not even output.txt is being generated.

`ShellExecute(
     0, 
     TEXT("open"), 
     TEXT("cmd.exe"), 
     TEXT("/C ipconfig > output.txt"), 
     NULL, 
     SW_HIDE
     );`

Comment: Specify a full path for the output file. For example, when I tested I use "/C ipconfig > C:\\Desktop\\output.txt". That worked well.

Comment: Ah yes this appears to be working. Let me test it further and get back to you.

Comment: Ok, I think im almost there but Im still having problems. I am trying to construct the string to be passed shellExecute. `C:\Program Files\Tools\ip.exe > C:\Documents and Settings\matt\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\GUIApp\output.txt` is what I have so far but its not working, trying to run it in cmd turns up a C:\Program is not a recognized as an internal or external command. Do I need to wrap some of my path in `" "` ?

Comment: Yes that's right. Put both the path to the .exe and the path to the output file inside double quotes.

Comment: Ok, so I have the following now But its not even producing a txt file anymore. `"C:\Program Files\Tools ip.exe" > "C:\Documents and Settings\matt\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\GUIApp\output.txt"`

Comment: I don't know. Hard to do in comments. I had no trouble. Does ip.exe have a requirement for the working directory to be set.

Comment: I understand that ye, sorry to be keeping you on this. ip.exe does require the working directory to be set yes. I cant understand why that itself isn't working.

Comment: OK, then set the working directory in the penultimate parameter to `ShellExecute`. Don't just copy my code without trying to understand it. Have a read of the MSDN docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `start` I think you might want to use `cd` to change the directory.

Try this batch file:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Tools\2012"
ip.exe >output.txt
```

Or for use without a batch and just command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\Tools\2012" ip.exe >output.txt"
```

Although `system32` is in `PATH` so I'm not sure why you are accessing the ipconfig exe by it's full path, but this should work.

Comment: I was only using ipconfig as an example. In the comments above I show the actual path to the tool I need ( `"start /D "C:\Program Files\Tools\2012" ip.exe > output.txt"`). ipconfig was just to help me understand the problem.

Comment: I am having some trouble with this. I am calling it by using `system("\"C:\Program Files\Tools\2012\" ip.exe >output.txt");` but no output.txt is generated.

Comment: Try redirecting the file to a set location, like `ip >C:\logfolder\output.txt`, it might be that the log file has tried to be created in the Program Files folder but doesn't have permission to.

Answer (score 0):

The error is this:

```
start /D "C:\>WINDOWS\system32" ipconfig.exe > output.txt
```

should be

```
start /D "C:\WINDOWS\system32" ipconfig.exe > output.txt
```

without `>` in the path. Although `C:\>` is shown at the prompt with `cmd.exe` it is *not* part of the path name and `>` is actually invalid for the purpose, to my knowledge.

Additionally I would strongly suggest you use:

```
start /D "%SystemRoot%\system32" ipconfig.exe > output.txt
```

---

Furthermore because start creates a new console (and new `stderr` and `stdout`) you are catching the output of `start` not of `ipconfig`. So you may wanna use:

```
pushd "%SystemRoot%\system32" & ipconfig.exe > output.txt & popd
```

but that will attempt to write `output.txt` into `%SystemRoot%\system32` and will fail on most systems unless you are admin. So give an absolute path or simply leave out the crud:

```
ipconfig.exe > output.txt
```

`ipconfig.exe` *is* always in the default system `PATH` variable, so it will work unless the admin has "fixed" the system in which case you can still do:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\ipconfig.exe > output.txt
```

Comment: You are correct. That was my mistake by copying it from the command prompt. My path does not include the `>`. And yes, I am capturing start which @David Heffernan pointed out in his comment. This is the issue I am trying to solve.